# Configuring Wix to add dependent dlls for firebreath Plugins

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, firebreath

Configured the firebreath generated Wix files to accept additional files but have had no success

```
   <!-- Put Additional files here: -->
  <!-- example:-->
   <Component Id="test" Guid="{104ca7b7-f654-481f9f6a-9a5b5a39c93b}">
        <File Id="test" KeyPath="yes" Source="C:\location\test.dll" />
    </Component>


    <Feature Id="MainPluginFeature" Title="${FBSTRING_ProductName}" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="InstallDirComp"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="PluginNameDirComp"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="CompanyDirComp"/>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="PluginDLLGroup"/>          
      <ComponentRef Id="test"/>
    </Feature>
```

> Errors: Error 8   error LGHT0204: ICE38: Component test installs to user
>   profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a
>   file.

I have tried the following but have ended up in errors,

- changing the GUID back to *
- adding directory=INSTALLDIR to the component
- Moving the component outside of Directory

I tried reading various forums and Wix documentation is not of much help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the ICE38 you need to add a dummy registry key and set your file's `KeyPath="no"`:

```
<Component Id="test" Guid="{104ca7b7-f654-481f9f6a-9a5b5a39c93b}">
   <File Id="test" KeyPath="no" Source="C:\location\test.dll" />
   <Registry Root=”HKCU” KeyPath=”yes” … />
</Component>
```

Comment: error CNDL0010: The Registry/@Key attribute was not found; it is required.

Comment: "dummy" registry key seems to suggest that i don't have to actually define keys

Comment: I meant dummy key to mean 'create any non-important key'. I would not have mentioned it if not needed.  __You__ need to fill in the "..." parts of `Registry` I do not know the rest of your WiX script as you did not post it. There should be other Firebreath generated Components in the script above this one that contain `Registry` elements that you can reference as examples.